# Get ISO 3166-2 Code from Bing Maps Locations API

Tags: bing-maps, iso-3166

Is there a way to get the [ISO 3166-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2) Code for a specific PostalCode/CountryCode Combination with the [Bing Maps Locations API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ff701715.aspx)?

Per Example: 1210/AT => AT-9

Answer (score 0):

Use the Bing Maps REST Location API and geocode your query (postal, country...). As part of the request add `&incl=ciso2` which will return the country's ISO2 code value. For example:

`https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?q=1210%2C%20AT&incl=ciso2&key=YOUR_Bing_Maps_Key`

Will return the following:

```
{
"authenticationResultCode": "ValidCredentials",
"brandLogoUri": "http:\/\/dev.virtualearth.net\/Branding\/logo_powered_by.png",
"copyright": "Copyright © 2017 Microsoft and its suppliers. All rights reserved. This API cannot be accessed and the content and any results may not be used, reproduced or transmitted in any manner without express written permission from Microsoft Corporation.",
"resourceSets": [{
    "estimatedTotal": 1,
    "resources": [{
        "__type": "Location:http:\/\/schemas.microsoft.com\/search\/local\/ws\/rest\/v1",
        "bbox": [48.237850189209, 16.3536491394043, 48.3225288391113, 16.4731197357178],
        "name": "1210, Austria",
        "point": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [48.2801895141602, 16.4104042053223]
        },
        "address": {
            "adminDistrict": "Vienna",
            "adminDistrict2": "Vienna",
            "countryRegion": "Austria",
            "formattedAddress": "1210, Austria",
            "locality": "Vienna",
            "postalCode": "1210",
            "countryRegionIso2": "AT"
        },
        "confidence": "High",
        "entityType": "Postcode1",
        "geocodePoints": [{
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [48.2801895141602, 16.4104042053223],
            "calculationMethod": "Rooftop",
            "usageTypes": ["Display"]
        }],
        "matchCodes": ["Good"]
    }]
}],
"statusCode": 200,
"statusDescription": "OK",
"traceId": "cb93431f2caa4f9fb2fcdbaa0ae80b74|CO30324109|7.7.0.0|"
}
```

Notice in the address property of the response there is `"countryRegionIso2": "AT"`

Documentation on the Bing Maps REST Locaiton API can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ff701711.aspx

There is a best practices guide here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn894107.aspx

If using .NET you may want to use the Bing Maps REST .NET Toolkit: https://github.com/Microsoft/BingMapsRESTToolkit It makes it really easy to use the REST services in .NET and also has a NuGet package for easily including in your project.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. But I don't need the country's ISO2 code. I need the  ISO 3166-2 Code (Subdivision) (see wikipedia Link).

Comment: Subdivision ISO2 codes are not available in the platform and there are no plans to add them.